# Get access token from dropbox api wihout user interaction

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api, core-api

I read the Dropbox core API authentication and in the documentation it is written that the user must open a link, copy the authorization code, paste it and then the API will change it to access token. Is there a way to avoid all that? for example when opening the Dropbox chooser and authenticating using email and password how do can I get access token as a result? any updates on that?

Note : The purpose is to get the access token as a result after the user signs in using Dropbox chooser API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course user interaction is required, but all the user needs to do is log in (if not already logged in) and click an "Allow" button to grant your app access. You might want to take a look at sample **web** apps (and not command-line examples). E.g. give https://mdwebhook.herokuapp.com/ a try and take a look at [the code](https://github.com/dropbox/mdwebhook).

Note that the Chooser won't give you an access token; it only gives you access to the specific file chosen by the user. To get an access token, you'll need to take the user through the OAuth flow. Perhaps Dropbox's [OAuth guide](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/oauth-guide) will help.

Comment: Unfortunately this seems the only way to do it, the problem is that I need to upload files from a server, not the client's machine. and the code you gave me looks good. Hope they change the OAuth flow soon.

Comment: "change the OAuth flow" in what way?

Comment: In google drive API, once the user logs in to google picker, he will get access token as a result. In Dropbox, the user must open a webpage, copy the authorization code, place it somewhere to later be converted to access token, as stated in this Dropbox tutorial [URL](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/start/php)

Comment: No, as I said, the user just needs to click a button that says "Allow." Please try the example I pointed you to. Did you need to copy an authorization code in that process?

Comment: this is not a solution in the case you only want to acquire a short live access token and use the token to upload some files. and repeat this each time there is file to upload.

Answer (score 0):

I guess and i hope thats not avoidable because of security reasons. I think there is no user who want to grant access or auth code without any interaction.

Comment: I mean after the client logs to Dropbox chooser using email and password, I want to get the access token as a result. Google API supports that, is there a way or workaround for Dropbox?